# Having trouble switching to user using the "su - lfs" command

Tags: ubuntu, su

I am trying to do linux from scratch. I was able to create the user to manage everything (named lfs) and I was able to login using this command. I then powercycled my computer and I am no longer able to switch to that user. If I enter `su - lfs` in my terminal I get the output `[1]+ Stopped su - lfs` after correctly entering the user password. Any ideas of how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow a `SIGSTOP` signal is sent to the `su` process. The interesting part is that only `root` processes are capable of sending signals to `su`. In other words: It cannot be the shell which is started by `su`. At least not directly; would have to be some `sudo` command or the like.

You can so this: Before you run `su - lfs` you run `echo $$` in order to get the PID of the shell. In a different terminal you then run:

```
strace -f -tt -p $PID -o shell.strace
```

Then you run `su - lfs`. After `su` has been stopped, you abort `strace` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and have a look at the file `shell.strace`. It should contain lines like

```
[pid 23558] --- SIGSTOP {si_signo=SIGSTOP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=23560, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 23558] --- stopped by SIGSTOP ---
```

That gives you the PID of the process that sent the signal.